# Expand range in macro

Tags: macros, elixir

I was wondering if it's somehow possible to expand ranges in macro's.

Currently when I try this code:

```
defmodule Main do
  defmacro is_atom_literal(char) do
    quote do:
      Enum.any?(unquote([?a..?z, ?A..?Z, ?0..?9, [?_, ?-]]), &(unquote(char) in &1))
  end

  def test do
    c = 'b'
    case c do
      c when is_atom_literal(c) ->
        :ok
    end
  end
end

Main.test
```

I get the error `"** (CompileError) test.ex: invalid quoted expression: 97..122"`. Is it possible to make this idea work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix "invalid quoted expression" you can use `Macro.escape/1` like this:

```
Enum.any?(unquote(Macro.escape([?a..?z, ?A..?Z, ?0..?9, [?_, ?-]])), &(unquote(char) in &1))
```

but then this throws another error:

```
** (CompileError) a.exs:10: invalid expression in guard
    expanding macro: Main.is_atom_literal/1
    a.exs:10: Main.test/0
```

This is because you're trying to call `Enum.any?/2` in a guard, which is not allowed.

Fortunately, there is a workaround this: just join all the expressions with `or`. This can be done using `Enum.reduce/3`:

```
defmacro is_atom_literal(char) do
  list = [?a..?z, ?A..?Z, ?0..?9, [?_, ?-]]
  Enum.reduce list, quote(do: false), fn enum, acc ->
    quote do: unquote(acc) or unquote(char) in unquote(Macro.escape(enum))
  end
end
```

What this code does is convert `is_atom_literal(c)` into:

```
false or c in %{__struct__: Range, first: 97, last: 122} or c in %{__struct__: Range, first: 65, last: 90} or c in %{__struct__: Range, first: 48, last: 57} or c in '_-'
```

which is a valid guard expression as Elixir later desugars `in` for ranges and lists into even simpler statements (something like `c >= 97 and c <= 122 or c >= 65 and c <= 90 or ...`).

The code still fails since your input is `'b'` while the macro expects one character. Changing `'b'` to `?b` works:

```
defmodule Main do
  defmacro is_atom_literal(char) do
    list = [?a..?z, ?A..?Z, ?0..?9, [?_, ?-]]
    Enum.reduce list, quote(do: false), fn enum, acc ->
      quote do: unquote(acc) or unquote(char) in unquote(Macro.escape(enum))
    end
  end

  def test do
    c = ?b
    case c do
      c when is_atom_literal(c) ->
        :ok
    end
  end
end

IO.inspect Main.test
```

Output:

```
:ok
```

Comment: Very nice, works great, thanks. Follow-up question: can you think of a nicer way to check if a single character is any character in that list? It's kind of messy now, having to reduce over it.

Comment: If there's only going to be these 4 ranges to check, I would probably just write the expanded form in the macro: `quote do: unquote(c) >= 65 and unquote(c) <= 90 or ...`.

Comment: Actually, you can make it better: `quote do: unquote(c) in ?a..?z or unquote(c) in ?A..?Z or ...`.